# Unable to forward data to elasticsearch without forwarding the data to aggregator

Tags: elasticsearch, fluentd

I am trying to forward rsyslog data from one server to elasticsearch directly below is the configuration written. When tried to run using this configuration

```
**Configuration:**

    <source>
     @type syslog
      port 42185
      tag  rsyslog
    </source>
    ##
    <match rsyslog.**>
      @type copy
      <store>
        type stdout
      </store>
      <store>
        @type elasticsearch
        logstash_format true
        retry_timeout 5s
        flush_interval 10s # for testing.
        logstash_prefix rsyslog_data
        type_name _doc
        default_elasticsearch_version 7.x
        host <ip>
        port <port>
      </store>
    </match>
```

It is not able to send data to elasticsearch but instead receiving below error.#

```
#2020-03-03 04:26:44 -0500 [warn]: #0 Could not communicate to Elasticsearch, resetting connection and trying again. read timeout reached#
2020-03-03 04:26:44 -0500 [warn]: #0 Remaining retry: 14. Retry to communicate after 2 second(s).
2020-03-03 04:26:46 -0500 [info]: Received graceful stop
2020-03-03 04:26:50 -0500 [info]: Received graceful stop
2020-03-03 04:26:53 -0500 [warn]: #0 Could not communicate to Elasticsearch, resetting connection and trying again. read timeout reached
2020-03-03 04:26:53 -0500 [warn]: #0 Remaining retry: 13. Retry to communicate after 4 second(s).
2020-03-03 04:27:06 -0500 [warn]: #0 Could not communicate to Elasticsearch, resetting connection and trying again. read timeout reached
2020-03-03 04:27:06 -0500 [warn]: #0 Remaining retry: 12. Retry to communicate after 8 second(s).
2020-03-03 04:27:09 -0500 [info]: Received graceful stop
2020-03-03 04:27:27 -0500 [warn]: #0 Could not communicate to Elasticsearch, resetting connection and trying again. read timeout reached
2020-03-03 04:27:27 -0500 [warn]: #0 Remaining retry: 11. Retry to communicate after 16 second(s).
2020-03-03 04:27:48 -0500 [info]: Received graceful stop
2020-03-03 04:28:04 -0500 [warn]: #0 Could not communicate to Elasticsearch, resetting connection and trying again. read timeout reached
2020-03-03 04:28:04 -0500 [warn]: #0 Remaining retry: 10. Retry to communicate after 32 second(s).
2020-03-03 04:29:13 -0500 [warn]: #0 Could not communicate to Elasticsearch, resetting connection and trying again. read timeout reached
2020-03-03 04:29:13 -0500 [warn]: #0 Remaining retry: 9. Retry to communicate after 64 second(s).
2020-03-03 04:31:26 -0500 [warn]: #0 Could not communicate to Elasticsearch, resetting connection and trying again. read timeout reached
2020-03-03 04:31:26 -0500 [warn]: #0 Remaining retry: 8. Retry to communicate after 128 second(s).
2020-03-03 04:33:40 -0500 [info]: Received graceful stop  
2020-03-03 04:35:47 -0500 [warn]: #0 Could not communicate to Elasticsearch, resetting connection and trying again. read timeout reached
2020-03-03 04:35:47 -0500 [warn]: #0 Remaining retry: 7. Retry to communicate after 256 second(s).#
```

Any idea would be of great help

Comment: No problem! It was quite messy. This way it can be better understood!

Comment: I literally tried for 30 minutes, It was really hard to post in apt format for the foryum, Any documentation you can suggest?

Comment: Posting a question from a web browser with a PC should be fine